# Projection Question - Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is:

> Suppose that $V=V_1\oplus V_2$ and let $L_1:V_1\to W$, $L_2:V_2\to W$ be a linear transformations. Show that there is a unique linear transformation $L:V\to W$ such that $L(v_1)=L_1(v_1)$ and $L(v_2)=L_2(v_2)$, for all $v_1\in V_1$ and $v_2\in V_2$.

So what I have so far is that if $V=V_1\oplus V_2$, a function $L:V\to V$ is a projection along $V_1$ along $V_2$ if, for $v=v_1+v_2$ with $v_1\in V_1$ and $v_2\in V_2$, we have $L(v)=v_1$.

But, I am suppose to show that $L=L_1P_1+L_2P_2$ where $P_1$, respectively, $P_2$ is the projection on $V_1$, respectively, $V_2$, along $V_2$, respectively $V_1$.

This is where I get thrown off. Thanks for the guidance in advance.

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there.

Your hypotheses
$L(v_1)=L_1(v_1)$ and $L(v_2)=L_2(v_2)$, for all $v_1\in V_1$ and $v_2\in V_2$ really mean
$$
L (P_1 (v)) = L_1(P_1(v)),
\qquad
L (P_2 (v)) = L_2(P_2(v))
$$
for all $v \in V$, so that $L$ is uniquely determined as
$$
L(v) = L(P_1(v) + P_2(v)) = L(P_1(v)) + L(P_2(v)) = L_1(P_1(v)) + L_2(P_2(v))
=
(L_1 P_1 + L_2 P_2)(v).
$$

Comment: How do I prove the hypotheses though?

Answer (score 2):

Base of $V_1\oplus V_2$=(base of${V_1})U ($ base of $V_2$)

and a linear transformation determine  uniquly by it's value on  domain space basis !